# Подсказки секций "голоса" и "все действия" в активности профиля написаны с маленькой буквы

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Подсказки секций "голоса" и "все действия" в активности профиля написаны с маленькой буквы:

[image: голоса]
[image: действия]

Для сравнения "реакции" (как и у всех остальных) с большой буквы:

[image: реакции]

При этом фразу "Голоса, отданные вами" возможно имеет смысл написать как "Отданные вами голоса". Сэкономим на запятой без потери смысла.